# Code coverage annotation for or statement next line or same line?

Tags: apex, unit-test, class, code-coverage

Ik have a class with several or statements. To make the code more readable I placed the or statements on a next line. My dev console shows that there is no coverage for these lines. Do I need to place the or statements on the same line of code to get coverage?

Here is my example:

```
if (addressRequired) {
            if (String.isBlank(klant.Street__c) 
            || String.isBlank(klant.PostalCode__c) 
            || String.isBlank(klant.City__c) 
            || String.isBlank(klant.CountryCode__c) 
            || ((klant.HouseNumber__c == null) && (klant.PoBox__c == null))) {
                eo_UtilsSF.log('klant= ' + klant);
                result.add('adres (Staging Klant)');
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the statements on different lines is definitely beneficial in terms of readability and is good practice. If done with SOQL statements they count as a single line for code coverage but in this case it doesn't.

The quick fix is yes, put it all on one line and it will count as fully covered, however it's a shame to lose the readability just for coverage. A different approach would be to make your unit test more comprehensive to cover all the lines.

The reason for this behaviour is due to how OR statements are assessed. If the left hand condition returns true then the right hand side is not evaluated - it knows it can return true without checking the rest of the chain. (N.B. If it was a chain of AND statements then it would need to cover every line before it can be sure of the overall result.)

I'm guessing in your test the first item `if (String.isBlank(klant.Street__c)` returns true, if you modify your test so that every element returns false up until the final one then you will get full coverage of this method.

On a side note, for true best practice you should really be aiming for full robust Unit Tests which check every aspect, ie a separate test checking each line of that statement, one where klant.Street__c is blank (but the other values are not), one where klant.Postcode__c is blank (but the other values are not) etc. and then validate the results as correct in each case.

It may feel a bit labour intensive but makes it easier to spot the source of a problem if it starts misbehaving in future.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question:

> Do I need to place the or statements on the same line of code to get coverage?

That's **correct**. To be able to get coverage on such scenarios, you will need to put your condition check in one single line. And this is based on the below excerpt from the [documentation on code coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm):

> If a statement consists of multiple expressions that are written on multiple lines, each line is counted for code coverage.

So, if you are having your unit tests based on one of the values and that you have the conditions spanned across different lines, then you need to put everything in single line.

I would echo what has been mentioned by **@Alex** in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/233648/54851) that to get a complete unit test, you should target to test all the condition in your if block (as in this case) and that way you can cover every aspect and still keep the readability aspect intact.